# Laravel Voyager: how to use my migration instead of Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, admin, database-migration

I try to set Laravel Voyager admin panel to existing project, i have already tables 'users', 'roles', 'permission', 'categories' etc. When I use `php artisan voyager:install`, I get an error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'avatar' (SQL: alter table `users` add `avatar` varchar(191) null after `email`, add `role_id` int null after `id`)

Voyager try to run his own migration and this leads to errors, how to tell Voyager to use my tables?

Answer (score 2):

when you install voyager admin panel in laravel it comes with some of table such as user table and permission table so since you have those table in database thus why it tells you column already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me; Your migration files should be up to date.

Mine was about categories.. I had to do a seed reversal of the data on my database after installing voyager so that my data would not be lost when I drop my database..It might be a little bit challenging for big data.

Here is the link to do that https://github.com/orangehill/iseed then after that I ran `php artisan migrate:fresh`  This  will drop the database and also recreate it with the former tables structure  and then execute the migrate command. Note the tables are going to be empty . And voyager is also going to work now without errors.

Then after that populate your tables again using the seeder command. Documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding

Another way to also solve this might be to revisit voyager source code and edit the variables; setting them to different values other than what you had set in your database:)